# How can I get parent node in JSONPATH

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

I have sample json format as per below

```
var myJSON = {
    section: "main",
    title: "xyz",
    child: [{
        title: "Home",
        isEnable: false,
        isActive: true
    }, {
        title: "Contact",
        isEnable: false,
        isActive: true
    }, {
        title: "Menu",
        isEnable: true,
        child: [{
            title: 'Sub-Menu-1',
            isEnable: true
        }, {
            title: 'Sub-Menu-2',
            isEnable: true,
            child: [{
                title: 'Sub-Menu-2-1',
                isEnable: false,
                isActive: true
            }, {
                title: 'Sub-Menu-2-2',
                isEnable: false,
                isActive: true
            }]
        }, {
            title: 'Sub-Menu-3',
            isEnable: true
        }, {
            title: 'Sub-Menu-4',
            isEnable: true
        }]
    }]
};
```

I want to get whole object with title name `Sub-Menu-2` if I match title with one of its child sub-menu title.
I have tried as per below but I didn't get as per my expectation

```
var result = jsonPath(myJSON , '$..*[?(@.title == "Sub-Menu-2-1")]');
```

my expected output is below

```
{
    title: 'Sub-Menu-2',
    isEnable: true
    child: [{
        title: 'Sub-Menu-2-1'
        isEnable: false,
        isActive: true
    }, {
        title: 'Sub-Menu-2-2',
        isEnable: false,
        isActive: true
    }]
}
```

Please help me to get expected output .Thanks in advance

Comment: The JSON structure you have posted is invalid. Please check that first.

Comment: @Pramod Karandikar  I have corrected JSON format

Answer (score 1):

For your expected output, you need to change the JSONPath expression.

```
$..[?(@.title =="Sub-Menu-2")]
```

This will give you the output:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Sub-Menu-2",
        "isEnable": true,
        "child": [
            {
                "title": "Sub-Menu-2-1",
                "isEnable": false,
                "isActive": true
            },
            {
                "title": "Sub-Menu-2-2",
                "isEnable": false,
                "isActive": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I want this output not by direct putting title string.I have provided demo JSON format.If I match any value with its child , I need the whole object with its  parent node. If my title match with "Sub-Menu-2-2" string , I need whole object with "Sub-Menu-2" title.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question which is "how do I get the parent of the object where title == 'Sub-Menu-2-1'"

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a node containing a child attribute that contains a title attribute that matches your text. Using the suggestion at the end of https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/287 you can get what you want with:

`$..[?(@.child[?(@.title=='Sub-Menu-2-1')] empty false)].title`